# Connecting to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to connect to google Spreadsheet via java according to https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java .

If I am executing this sample on my IDE, it's working without problems.
Now I want to integrate this sample into my android app. The first activity directly calls the main-method of the previous link (code is in step3 of link. The main method has been renamed, in order to be called by the activity). But I am getting an Error:

```
    W/System.err: java.io.IOException: unable to create directory: /tokens
    W/System.err:     at com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory.<init>(FileDataStoreFactory.java:61)
    W/System.err:     at com.kazumi.management.ConnectToDatabase.getCredentials(ConnectToDatabase.java:70)
```

According to the error, it should be this line:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
```

So the reason is, that this function isn't able to create a directory on my virtual android device. But why is it like that? And does there exist a workaround?

Comment: You'll probably have better luck with the dedicated [Android library](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/android).

Comment: @Phix Do you happen to know a link to a tutorial/instruction guide to access and read google sheets ?

Comment: I didn't look too far into it before posting, but it does say after the gradle deps the Java guides will work.  I'm guessing the way Android creates files is different from regular ol' java does, so I suggest replacing problematic code with the Android version. In this case, instead of `new java.io.File...`, you'd use whatever Android provides (it's been a while since I've used it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution by myself. Internal and External Storage are difficult to access on android (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

So in order to create a directory on my internal storage, I need to use this:

```
File folder = getDir("theFolder",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```